# Safe sustained operating temperatures on CPU(Ryzen9)

Tags: cpu, hardware-failure, temperature

I am contributing my compute to [Folding@Home](https://foldingathome.org/). However until now I have only used the GPU for folding, since my Ryzen9 3900x got to 93C and stayed there when folding. On various forums I heard that for a sustained temperature that is way too high and can seriously hurt the chip over time.

[AMD max temp](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-9-3900x) is said to be 95C. So is a 24/7 operating temperature bad for the chip or is that a non-issue? When looking and asking around I got very conflicting answers and found nothing on the topic by AMD themselves.

On sustained synthetic stress tests like CPUZ which puts all cores at 100% load, the temperatures never exceed 75C. It seems the additional heat from the heavy cache usage is heating up the chip even more(just my speculation).

[Rig for context](https://pcpartpicker.com/list/qqw7Pn)

Does `Max Temps: 95°C` like on the amd page mean that this is a safe sustained temperature, or does it mean that peaks should only be this high?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Authoritative Answer: Reply from AMD Tech support:

> Dear [jaaq],
>
> [...]
>
> You can use the CPU at 85C-90C for 24/7 operation without any worry about CPU lifespan.
>
> Thank you for contacting AMD.
>
> [...]

I asked for the Ryzen 9 3900x specifically, so take this with a grain of salt if you have a different chip.

Comment: Just FYI to for future readers...  I have a 3700X that I use in the same capacity (on the BOINC network) and my proc runs consistently at 87C.  I asked AMD the same question and got this response: **"The maximum temperature of AMD Ryzen 7 3700X is 95°C. Issue occur only when it crosses maximum temperature."**  So they seem to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

93 is pushing it a little.  If you can (say you have some spare case fans around or a better CPU Heat-Sink) you might want to install more cooling in your system.   The AMD CPUs are quite heat tolerant (far more than Intel due to using thermal solder instead of paste) but you are hitting heat throttling at that point, and will be losing performance in other tasks.

If you are using Linux you may want to use thermald to run a script to dynamically sleep your folding@home client when the temperatures get hot, then ramping back up whenever they cool down.  This will address the issue.

I believe there are similar options for Windows and Mac.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I know of these options, but I am unsure as to where to set the trigger. Since the CPU heats up to about 70C when using the GPU only(in which case 1 thread is always running at 100%, (probably)to serve the GPU with tasks), I need to know a maximum temperature I can safely aim for running at 24/7. I know of the possibilities of ramping down tasks, etc. That's what I am looking to do, I just want this chip to not deteriorate for at least 5 years; so I need credible source link that tells me what sustained max temperature to aim for.